# Merge 2 RTF texts with images

Tags: delphi, rtf

I am using the following method for concatenating two separate RTF texts and finally display the result on a `TcxCustomRichEdit` control. It is working perfectly from years. Now I need to support Images too in RTF text.
The problem is when there are images in `TcxCustomRichEdit` controls, it concatenates but simply excludes the images.

How can I achieve this ?

Sample Code : Sample code is taken from http://delphi.about.com/od/tmemotrichedit/a/richedit-append.htm and modified

In the code as you can see that there are two `TcxCustomRichEdit` placed and finally after concatenation Results are shown on First `TcxCustomRichEdit` Control.

```
Procedure AppendFromRichEdit(FromRch,ToRch: TcxCustomRichEdit); // Function to append rich edit text from source to Destination
var
  MemStream: TMemoryStream;
   rtfStream: TEditStream;


   function EditStreamReader(
    dwCookie: DWORD;
    pBuff: Pointer;
    cb: LongInt;
    pcb: PLongInt): DWORD; stdcall;
  begin
    result := $0000;
    try
      pcb^ := TStream(dwCookie).Read(pBuff^, cb) ;
    except
      result := $FFFF;
    end;
  end; (*EditStreamReader*)

begin
   MemStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
   try
     with FromRch as TcxCustomRichEdit do Begin
         Lines.SaveToStream( MemStream );
     end;
    MemStream.Position := 0;
    rtfStream.dwCookie := DWORD(MemStream) ;
    rtfStream.dwError := $0000;
    rtfStream.pfnCallback := @EditStreamReader;
    Try
      ToRch.InnerControl.Perform(
        EM_STREAMIN,
        SFF_SELECTION or SF_RTF or SFF_PLAINRTF, LPARAM(@rtfStream)
      ) ;
      if rtfStream.dwError <> $0000 then
        raise Exception.Create(TranslateQBMessage('QBToolsErrorAppendingRTFData'));
    except
      On E: Exception do
       // do nothing      MsgBox(E.Message)
    end;
   finally
      MemStream.Free;
   end;
end;

procedure ConcatenateAndShow;
var
  redTemp: TcxRichEdit;
begin
  try
    redTemp := TcxRichEdit.Create(memTesto.Owner);
    redTemp.Parent := memTesto.Parent;
    redTemp.Visible := False;
    redTemp.Clear;
    redTemp.Text := MySecondRichEditControl.Text; //Text in Second Rich Edit Control
    AppendFromRichEdit(redTemp, memTesto);
  finally
    redTemp.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FirstRicheditControl.lines.Append('This is My Text in First Richedit Control');
  FirstRicheditControl.lines.Append('And Finally after concatenation it will show in Same Control');
  ConcatenateAndShow;
end;
```

Comment: Review the question, please. I've highlighted `TcxCustomRichEdit` since it might be little bit different from `TRichEdit`, even though they might have many things common.

Comment: The [`original code`](http://delphi.about.com/od/tmemotrichedit/a/richedit-append.htm) works fine even with images; tested on `TJvRichEdit` controls.

Answer (score 1):

in the function ConcatenateAndShow adding redTemp.properties.AllowObjects = True may solve the problem because dault value of allowobejcts property is false, so it is not allowing the image object in RTF

```
Try
redTemp := TcxRichEdit.Create(memTesto.Owner);
redTemp.Parent := memTesto.Parent;
redTemp.Visible := False;
redtemp.Properties.AllowObjects := True;
.
.
```

Comment: +1, good point, @user193655, check if you have `Properties.AllowObjects` on a target `TcxRichEdit` set to True. I've tried it now and with `TcxRichEdit`s placed on the form with the only one change `Properties.AllowObjects := True` your code works as expected.